# using CMP statements in assembly language

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I would like to use comparing statements and user inputs in assembly language. After I take in a user input, it will compare the statements and perform the task. However, regardless of results, it will only read the first comparison statement and perform the task even though it does not meet the criteria.

```
    bl _inputFunc

    cmp r1, #1
    beq _redLight
    cmp r1, #2
    beq _greenLight
    cmp r1, #3
    beq _offLight

    _redLight:
            GPIOWrite   pin17, high
            bl _inputFunc
            
    _greenLight:
            GPIOWrite   pin18, high
            bl _inputFunc

    _offLight:
            GPIOWrite   pin17, low
            GPIOWrite   pin18, low
            bl _inputFunc
```

Comment: Remember that labels are not functions; they do not affect program flow by themselves, and only serve as targets for branches.  So after `cmp r1, #3 ; beq _offLight`, if the branch is not taken, execution will "fall through" to `GPIOWrite pin17, high` at label `_redLight`. If you want it to go somewhere else, you need an unconditional branch. Likewise, after the `bl _inputFunc` in `_redLight` returns, execution falls through into `_greenLight`.

Comment: By the way, the "snippet" feature only works for Javascript / HTML / CSS.  Don't use it for other languages such as assembly; it adds "run" buttons that don't work, and messes up syntax highlighting.  Just use "code sample" instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hello, thanks for the reply, will also take note of the snippet feature. If i am understanding this right, I would need to create an uncondition branch after all of my bl _inputFunc so that the program will keep on comparing?

Comment: Yes, you need an unconditional branch after each one.  You could branch back to the top of the code (add a label there) if you want to continue the loop, or branch somewhere else if your program wants to do something different.

Comment: Actually, if I understand your code correctly, you probably want to branch straight back to the `bl _inputFunc` at the top after `GPIOWrite`.  There's no need to have a separate call in each of the three cases.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am sorry but I am not sure how to brach straight back to the bl _input Func at the top after GPIOWrirte. From my understanding, I thought I did that when i call bl _inputFun after GPIOWrite

Answer (score 2):

In machine code, after any instruction that is not a branch, execution continues with the next instruction in memory.  This includes conditional branches that are not taken.  Inserting labels between the instructions does not change that.  Labels are not functions or blocks, and there is no implicit "return" or any such thing at the "end" of a label; indeed a label has no such thing as an "end".

Do not try to think of assembly in terms of higher-level constructs like `if/else` or `while` or `switch`, at least not directly.  There are only branches (the equivalent of `goto ...`) and conditional branches (`if (cond) goto ...`).  Any higher-level abstraction is up to you to implement in terms of these building blocks.  All the lessons you learned about not using `goto` when programming are out the window; in assembly you don't have anything *but* `goto`.

Assuming that this program is supposed to be an infinite loop, I would write it as

```
_top:
    bl _inputFunc

    cmp r1, #1
    beq _redLight
    cmp r1, #2
    beq _greenLight
    cmp r1, #3
    beq _offLight
    // if we reach here, we got an input out of range.
    // insert error handling code here
    b _top // continue looping

_redLight:
    GPIOWrite   pin17, high
    b _top
            
_greenLight:
    GPIOWrite   pin18, high
    b _top

_offLight:
    GPIOWrite   pin17, low
    GPIOWrite   pin18, low
    b _top
```

I took out your extra indentation, which seems to contribute to the misconception that assembly is a block-structured language.  Also, there is no need to call `_inputFunc` within each of the three cases; they might as well just branch back to `_top` where there is already a call to it.

I kept your convention of naming labels with a leading underscore, but in a standalone program there is normally no need to do that, and you might as well just call them `top`, `redLight`, etc.

Comment: I am getting an illegal instruction error, to call the top function in my start, I would need to call it as b _top?

Comment: @JoyCheng: Probably, but without seeing the rest of your code I cannot say for sure.  (But again, I suggest not trying to think in terms of "function" and "call".  A branch is a goto, nothing more.)

Comment: `_start: GPIOExport  pin17
        GPIOExport  pin18

        nanoSleep

        GPIODirectionOut pin17
        GPIODirectionOut pin18

        
        bl _top`

this is how i am calling it in my main function

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether you `b _top` or `bl _top`; it is never going to return so it is irrelevant whether you save a return address or not.  But simpler still would be to place the code starting with `_top` immediately after `GPIODirectionOut pin18`, so that you just execute it directly without needing a branch.

Comment: Hi, just an update. I have tried your suggestion but I am back to square one again where my red light will on even though my input is 2 or 3.

Comment: Your code at `_greenLight` only turns on the green light; it does not change the state of the red light.  If it was already on, it stays on.  If you want it to also turn the red light off, you need to add `GPIOWrite   pin17, low` at `_greenLight`.  I don't know why 3 would fail to turn both lights off.  I can't test it because I don't have your hardware.  It's possible that `_inputFunc` or `GPIOWrite` don't work the way you think they do.  Perhaps you can run your code under a debugger and see what it is actually doing.